# Removed laptop from Azure AD Devices - non admin user on device can't log off unlink Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, office365, azure, azure-activedirectory

I need to unlink a computer form a Microsoft 365 account to join the computer on an on-premise AD Domain.

At the moment the linked account can't be removed from "Access work or school" section (the button is grey). I have global admin on this o365 tenant but I can't run any process as administrator using my admin account credentials because it doesn't recognize it (Username or account invalid).

The local administrator account is disabled and it can't be enabled with this account.
The device have been already deleted from Azure AD.

Edit: I only have remote access to this machine.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to boot with some Linux distro and once done go to the old C:\windows\system32 (very of the it mounted on Z:)
Once there you can rename the utility manager (utliman.exe)

```
ren Utilman.exe Utilman.exe.old
```

Then copy command line to overwrite the utility manager

```
copy cmd.exe Utilman.exe
```

Boot and hit the button utility (on windows 10) it similar to a clock on the right bottom corner and once you get the cmd with admin privilege you cand run this

```
net user Administrator MY NEW PASSWORD$
```

Also, enable if it's disabled

```
net user Administrator /active:yes
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only have remote access to this machine.

Comment: But the local account it's a local admin or not? If yes you can use it to enable and change the local admin password.

Comment: Maybe you can try this workaround:
Steps:

- Settings, Accounts

- Select "instead log on with a local account" and follow the steps

- Then logon, go back to accounts, and go to Access to work and school account

- Retry the remove and it will work

- Last step, go back and change logon to be with Microsoft Account instead of local account

Comment: No, the account my user use to log in, is not an admin, I can't enable the local Administrator account.

Comment: Sorry to tell but you are doom. Need some remote hand to fix. You may try to add again following my early comment